# Remove components after setup in OpenMDAO

Tags: openmdao

I would like remove (or redefine) a component after setup. Is this possible with [the reconfigurable model execution](https://doi.org/10.2514/6.2017-3821)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is technically possible with reconfigurability. However, as of openmdao 2.2.1 that is not a fully supported feature. You'll need to experiment a bit on your own.

There are some [tests](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/409f2b97cbc5e7200511b448e27a433bf99efd64/openmdao/core/tests/test_reconf_group.py) that can show you how to get started.